# How do I do a "natural sort" in PyICU?

Tags: python, icu

Using PyICU, how can I use a Collator to sort a list of strings by "natural order", i.e., putting 10 after 2 instead of before?

In the ICU docs http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation/customization#TOC-Default-Options, I can see that there is a "numericOrdering" option (a.k.a. UCOL_NUMERIC_COLLATION) that can be set on or off, but I can't figure out how to set that attribute from Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.setAttribute` method on the Collator instance.

The attribute name and value come from an enum that's attached to the main `icu` module:

```
import icu

collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale('en_US'))
collator.setAttribute(icu.UCollAttribute.NUMERIC_COLLATION, icu.UCollAttributeValue.ON)

sorted(['3 three', '1 one', '10 ten', '2 two'])
# ['1 one', '10 ten', '2 two', '3 three']

sorted(['3 three', '1 one', '10 ten', '2 two'], key=collator.getSortKey)
# ['1 one', '2 two', '3 three', '10 ten']
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but there is an alternative mechanism within ICU4C for refining collation.

A more flexible approach is to use BCP47 U extension to set aspects of the collation, rather than creating a Collator instance then setting the relevant attributes.

1. create a locale form a  BCP47 language tag, numeric collation can be specified using the `-u-kn-true` extension.
2. Create a collator instance
3. Sort

```py
import icu
locale = icu.Locale.forLanguageTag("en-u-kn-true")
collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(locale)
sorted(['3 three', '1 one', '10 ten', '2 two'], key=collator.getSortKey)
# ['1 one', '2 two', '3 three', '10 ten']
```